# filter file with specift words linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have files in which the first column is an ID, and the second column is an option, like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
 1234;m11
 6758;m11;m14
 8796;mm14
 0303;m11
```

and I need to create a files with the IDs depending with the option. It is to say:

```
file_m11.txt => (1234,0303)
file_m11_m14 => (6758)
file_mm14 => (8796)
```

I try with `cat file.txt | grep -w "option" > file_option` but the problem is that the files are mutually exclusive, and the result is

```
file_m11.txt => (1234,0303,*6758*)
file_m11_m14 => (6758)
file_mm14 => (8796,*6758*)
```

Since I do in order that this does not happen, (the options can be change the name)

Comment: Look at Bash associate arrays to accumulate the table and the readarray command to read each line.  For the latter, you will need to set IFS.

Comment: When you say  "I need to create a files with the IDs depending with the option"  you're saying that you want to create individual files for each option combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m11;m14` is a single "option"  you could modify your grep like

```
grep -P '^\s*\d+;option$' file > file_option
```

`-P` uses perl style regex, which is often nicer to look at and easier to work with.  Then the regular expression looks for a line that starts with 0 or more spaces (or tabs), then some digits the a semicolon then your option and the end of the line.  So `m14` won't match `m11;m14` because the start of the line doesn't match the pattern, and `m11` won't match `m11;m14` because the end of the line won't match.

It won't put the parens or put everything on the same line as in your examples, but your attempt at the command won't do that either, so I'm assuming that isn't actually important right now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether I fully understood the question (see comment above), but here goes.

If you save the below as e.g. split.awk

```
{
  a=gensub(/^([^;]+).*/,"\\1",1);
  file=gensub(/[0-9]+;(.*)/,"\\1",1);
  gsub(/;/,"_",file); 
  store[file] = ""store[file]""a","
}
END{
  for( options in store ){
    gsub( /^/, "(", store[options])
    gsub( /,$/, ")", store[options])
    print store[options]  >> "file_"options".txt"
  }
}
```

And run it like so:

```
awk -f split.awk file.txt
```

This will create:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink   tink     7 2015-05-19 08:29 file_mm14.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink   tink    12 2015-05-19 08:29 file_m11.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink   tink     7 2015-05-19 08:29 file_m11_m14.txt
```

With the content as indicated above.